# Returning a subset of list and dictionaries, from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to return a subset of list of dictionaries, derived from a list of dictionaries.

Input:

```
dicts = [
    {'name': 'Sam', 'age': 12},
    {'name': 'Pete', 'age': 14}, 
    {'name': 'Sarah', 'age': 16}
]
```

Im trying to get this output:

```
res = [
    {'name': 'Sam'},
    {'name': 'Pete'}, 
    {'name': 'Sarah'}
]
```

So far i've been trying with this approach:

```
res = []

def new_dict(dicts):
    for i in range(len(dicts)):
        for k, v in dicts[i]:
            if dicts[i][k] == 'name'
                res.append(dicts[i][k] = v)

print(new_dict(dicts))
```

Comment: `res = [{'name': d['name']} for d in dicts]`

Answer (score 2):

With list comprehension you can do:

```
[{'name': x['name']} for x in dicts]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

The safer method (That won't fail if one of your dicts doesn't have a `name` value):

```
[{'name': x['name']} for x in dicts if 'name' in x]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Much appriciated